# Viewport Shading gray. I must have pressed something because it was all fine a minute ago

Tags: rendering

Does anybody know why my Viewport Shading has gone all grey. I must have pressed something because it was all fine a minute ago.. In other mode, that fine.[image]

Comment: check your Viewport Shading panel and disable Scene World option?

Comment: Je suis nouveau là-dedans.. Tu veux dire quoi pour le panneau des Viewport? J'ai essayé de regarder des vidéos pour mon problème mais aucun n'est pour ma version..

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.